# How do I call a value from a file that i wrote and turn it as a variable to use to compare to another key in another list?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary "Pokemon" being written to a file "UPoke" later on i want to take the type value and compare it to another value from another file "EPoke"

I'am asking the user to input their pokemon and stats and of the ones they input i want to compare "type" to an enemy pokemon which they will also enter the info for.

```
         UsersPoke = open("UPoke", "w")

print ("Please enther the required information for each Pokemon up to 3. Type 'q' when done.")
def UPoke1(poke_name, hp, defense, type):
    poke_name = poke_name.strip()
    hp = hp.strip()
    defense = defense.strip()
    type = type.strip()

    Pokemon = {"Name":poke_name, "HP":hp, "DEF:":defense, "Type": type}
    return Pokemon

#user Input for their Pokemon
    
while True:
    
    poke_name = input ("Enter The Pokemon Name: ")
    hp = input ("Enter your Pokemons HP: ")
    defense = input ("Enter your pokemons Defense: ")
    type = input ("What is your Pokemons Type ('water,fire,grass): ")

    if poke_name != 'q' or hp != 'q' or defense != "q" or type != "q" :
        Pokemon = UPoke1(poke_name, hp, defense, type)
        UsersPoke.write(str(Pokemon))
    else:
        delay_print ("Saving...\n")
        break
    
UsersPoke.close()
```